# cypress code coverage for react application

Tags: reactjs, cypress, cypress-code-coverage

I am facing below issue while making code coverage of my application. My application has below folder structure.

[image: folder structure]

Help me to get code coverage of all src folder.

Comment: @TesterDick Can you help in this

Comment: Any suggestion/ ideas on above question would be really appreciated.